# Productivity Power tools for Microsoft Visual studio 2012 not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, productivity-power-tools

I have always used eclipse for doing c++ work, but now I have access to an ultimate VS license through my university. I've been trying it out but the one thing I can't get over is that it doesn't automatically close curly braces, parenthesis, etc. I have installed the Productivity Power Tools extension which is supposed to add this feature, but even though it shows up in the list of installed extensions and I have enabled the feature in the Extension settings, it still doesn't auto-complete my braces. How can I fix this?

Comment: I suspect that that PPT feature is C# only.

Comment: ahhhh it seems as though you are right. Thats dissapointing, but thank you.

Comment: [Visual Assist-X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

Productivity tools seems not to support native C++, only managed langugae (C#, C++ and vb).
Better use [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for it.